# How to use 'Ignore or Validate' in JSON file (karate framework)?

Tags: karate

I have to verify that each response is in correct format. I've put in my feature:

`And match each response contains { id: '#string', name: '#string', phone: '#number' etc..}`

But I would like to put this in a JSON file, beacuse I need it several times in different features.
When I use 'Ignore or Validate' tags in JSON file, it doesn't work. Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes why not. First place the following in a file called `item-schema.json`.

```
{ "id": "#string", "name": "#string", "phone": "#number" }
```

Now all you need to do is:

```
And match each response contains read('item-schema.json')
```

Please go through the documentation of [Reading Files](https://github.com/intuit/karate#reading-files) carefully.